# Main.axml cant be opened VS2015

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by a misconfiguration of Java

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

The value in my environment variable **PATH** is

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin

Answer (score 0):

I got same error.

Mine was fixed by changing the following

Naivgate to the .Droid project, 
Right Click -> properties 
Select Application 
Set Minimum Android to Target -> Andriod4.0.3 (API level15 - Ice Cream Sandwich)
Target Android Version -> Use Compile using Sdk Version